# iMovie App Preview video "in wrong format" for iPad

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, imovie

iMove 10.1
OS X 10.11.1

I created a "New App Preview" in iMovie - I'm using a combination of screen capture/transitions and titles screens, but the first 0.1 is a clean, uncropped screen capture from iPad - that seemed to be an issue for others with this problem.

I'm only uploading the video for iPad, currently.

The video uploads and looks fine - I can set the Poster Frame - but when I go to save it, I get the following error:

[image: iTunes Connect Error]

I've followed the guidlines, it's a 28s video, the aspect ratio is correct etc. and the export settings are the default ones for exporting to the App Store. Could it be that I have to upload a video for ALL device types?!

The movie timeline looks like this:

[image: iMovie timeline]

and the export looks like this:

[image: iMovie export]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to an Apple rep on Nov 7 about this problem, and they confirmed it was a problem on their side and that many developers have been affected. Basically, all app previews are being rejected as "wrong format." No estimated time to a fix. Their recommendation was to just keep trying it…

Comment: That is remarkable, and disconcerting. Thanks so much for sharing your insight - saved me from a day of rebuilding the video in the hopes of "fixing" whatever Apple didn't like

Comment: did you file a radar ticket?

Comment: Yes, I filed an iTunesConnect bug to add to their pile. They confirmed getting many other developers have been complaining about this problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, iTunesConnect appears to be allowing video submissions again. The "wrong format" bug appears squashed.

Comment: I received a reply to my bug report stating that the developers have addressed this bug as of 5pm on Nov 10, however iTunesConnect is still erroneously throwing App Preview errors hours after submitting the videos.

Comment: Any updates on this, I still experience the same problem.